# How do I make a Div inside an other div have width in percantage of body width instead of boundingbox?

Tags: css

The code looks like this:

```
<body>
        <div id='1'>
           <div id='2'>
           </div>
        </div>
```

css:

```
        #1 {
         width:              62%;
        }

       #2 {
         width:              28%;
        }
```

Because the width of the inner div is relative to the width of the outer div, the inner divs width will be 0.62*0.28*"body width". This makes the proportions of the divs not maintain when I rescale the window. Is there a way to have the inner div have it's size relative to the bodys width?

Comment: I have no clue what your question is about :)

Comment: That's the whole idea of nesting elements. If you want the width relative to the BODY, then move the 2nd DIV outside.

Comment: Kristofer, you've said that inner div's width is always 0.62*0.28 = 0.1736 of body width. So, proportion is maintained.

Comment: Casablanka: this is just a simpifield version, in the actual case, it's a fieldset and fields, and due to a lot of other styling i Can't move it outside. Nikita: The problem is that the outer divs proportion to the body is 0.62, so it "shrinks faster" when you risize the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always scale your inner width taking into account the outer width, for eg. `(100 / 62) * 28 = 45`, so if you make your inner DIV `45%`, it will be `28%` relative to the BODY.

Comment: That sounds great for maintaining the proporitons! However, then I can't control the width of the inner div. Because of stuff inside the inner div, I can't use padding either. I would need something like widht: 10%+20px; is that possible to do?

Comment: @Kristoffer: No, you can only specify either a percentage or an absolute width, not both.

Comment: @Kristoffer Why exactly you can't use padding, again?

Comment: Because it's actually a "field" not a div (:

Comment: I ended up setting all the margins etc to % and it worked out!

Comment: @Kristoffer: You can try using `display: inline-block` on the "fields" -- that should let you add padding to them.

Answer (score -1):

`id`s cannot start with a number. If you change the `id`s from `1` and `2` to `foo` and `bar`, it'll work.

Comment: That is just some sample code, and the ID's are not at all related to the question. :)

Comment: @Kristoffer Oh. Well before you edited the question title (i.e. when your question was still relatively unclear), the obvious syntax errors in your code seemed the likely culprit.

Comment: ah, I get it, sorry. I can't remove the vote within an hour, but then i'll totaly remove it :)

Comment: Seems like you have to change the content of the answer for me to be able to remove the vote...